# Is OpenID Connect migration required if the following sequence of requests is currently used?

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid

I just inherited several projects which allow the users to authenticate with Google accounts.

I am now trying to figure out if there are any changes that **must** be done so that Google authentication still works after the 20th of April 2015, when Open ID 2.0 is Shut Down (see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID)

I am aware that the End Points should not be hardcoded and https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration should be used instead, but this task is currently set on low priority.

Below is the request sequence that is currently used.

Thanks!

**1. Authentication URI**

```
Base URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
Parameters:
scope{
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
}
redirect_uri{
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
}
response_type{
code
}
client_id{
<<my client id>>
}
login_hint{
<<user's email address>>
}
```

**2. Exchange Token URI**

```
Base URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
Parameters: 
client_id{
<<my client id>>
}
client_secret{
<<my client secret>>
}
redirect_uri{
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
}
grant_type{
authorization_code
}
access_token{
<<token received from Authentication URI>>
}
```

**3. API call URI**

```
Base URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
Parameters:
access_token{
<<token received from Exchange Token URI
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using OAuth2 (note your authentication URL "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" corresponds to [Google OAuth2 endpoint](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl)), so no changes required -- your application should continue to work after Google's OpenID shutdown.

Hope that helps!